# custom MKAnnotation class for changing leftCalloutAnnotationView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a custom class for the MKAnnotation

```
@interface NeighborMapAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
    NSString * title;
    NSString * subtitle;
    UIImageView * lcav;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView * lcav;
@end



NeighborMapAnnotation *neighbor = [[NeighborMapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:aCoordinate];
//imgView is some UIImageView that I already have
neighbor.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imgView;


- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{

    MKPinAnnotationView * annView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"custom view"] autorelease];
    annView.animatesDrop = YES;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    annView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [annotation lcav];//is this right?

    return annView;
}
```

I want to be able to change the leftCalloutAccessoryView of the annotation to an image. What code should I change in my custom MKAnnotation class?

Comment: edited the code above as per suggestion below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leftCalloutAccessoryView property is a property of the MKAnnotationView class (not in the MKAnnotation protocol).

In the viewForAnnotation delegate method of MKMapView, you provide an MKAnnotationView for your annotations.  In that method, check if the annotation type is your custom annotation type using isKindOfClass and set the view's properties as needed.

In your NeighborMapAnnotation class, you could store the imageView as a UIImageView property and set that when creating the annotation.

In viewForAnnotation, you would set the view's leftCalloutAccessoryView to the annotation's imageView.

**Edit:**
Here's one way to implement it...

Add an image property to your custom annotation class:

```
@interface NeighborMapAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    ...
    UIImage *image;
}
...  
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;
@end
```

At the place where you create your annotations, set the image property:

```
NeighborMapAnnotation *neighbor = [[NeighborMapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:aCoordinate];
neighbor.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someimage.png"];
//the image could be different for each annotation
...
```

In the viewForAnnotation delegate method (make sure map view's delegate is set):

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[NeighborMapAnnotation class]])
    {
        static NSString *AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
        MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];
        if (!pinView)
        {
            pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
            pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        UIImageView *leftCalloutView = [[UIImageView alloc] 
            initWithImage:((NeighborMapAnnotation *)annotation).image];
        pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftCalloutView;
        [leftCalloutView release];

        return pinView;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: will this allow me to have a different leftCalloutAccessoryView to different images for different pins?

Comment: Yes, I'll add some example code shortly.  The MapCallouts sample app also shows how to do this.

Comment: I just saw that example, but that means that for every pin the image will be the same right? I want it to be able to have different image... I want to be able to say neighbor.lcav = some UIImageView

Comment: I edited my code above based on my understanding, please let me know what I did wrong

Comment: Your code looks like it should work now except that `neighbor.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imgView;` should be `neighbor.lcav = imgView;`.  You will also get a warning on the `[annotation lcav]` line.

Comment: Also, you should use dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier for more efficient memory usage.

Comment: Sorry, made a correction to the viewForAnnotation method so it uses the right image when the annotation view is re-used.  Please try the latest version.

Comment: the only problem is that the image that I have is so huge, and I want it to show at an appropriate size.. how can I set it so that the image displayed is resized to say 25x25 px

Comment: The MapCallouts sample app also does image resizing in the viewForAnnotation method.  It does it for flagImage--see the code.  You would set maxSize to 25,25.  However, I suggest, if possible, to resize your images to that size once in some imaging utility and add those thumbnails to your project (along with the hi-res ones if you need them).  Resizing images at run-time may not perform well especially for large images.

Answer (score 1):

thats great! i tried to extend my custom annotation class by few properties. but i had no access inside of viewForAnnotation delegate. what i´ve missed and learned here is that i have to cast the additional property on my custom annotation class. now it works! thank you! :-)