# How to pass image data from NSdictionary to annotation.image

Tags: ios, annotations

How to pass image data from `NSDictionary` to `annotation.image` like `annotation.title` and `annotation.subtitle` on below method

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation”
```

because I need to use image to leftCalloutAccessoryView.
I already add `@property (copy, nonatomic) NSData *image;` to `MyAnnotation.h`

Next pass data to below method `([[view annotation]image]) like  [[view annotation]title] and [[view annotation]subtitle]` because I need to send image data to next UIViewController.

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

Thanks.

Comment: Set the property when adding the annotation and access it in the delegate methods by first casting the annotation object to your type.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841753/custom-mkannotation-class-for-changing-leftcalloutannotationview.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the left and right callout in – mapView:didSelectAnnotationView: delegate method. So, your code

```
  annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = yourImage;
  annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
```

Hope this helps.:)